# save output stats to file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, putty, grass

I am working with GRASS GIS using PuTTy console and I would like to save statistics that I received, to text file.

```
> r.stats -c xyz
1 286048
2 151
3 473
4 12030
5 197
* 107401
```

I want to use awk to create matrix, but my problem is to save result of proper command that I used.

I know that in general it could be like:

```
> awk -F "{print $1 $2}" from >> to
```

But how should it look like in my case?

Comment: How do you want your matrix to look like and single quote the `Awk` command, else it will treat `$1` and `$2` are positional arguments which will expand to nothing in this case

Comment: What exactly should be the format of the output matrix? I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have raster of healthy and dead trees. This result shows numbers of pixels from one raster that cover the same class in other raster. I would like to have matrix 2x2 with: healthy-healthy, healthy-dead, dead-healthy, dead-dead. But firstly just to save it in proper way to text file.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: For example, this data should be printed like that: first row: 151,473 second row: 12030, 197. as a matrix 2x2

Comment: what happens to the first and last row?  What are the rules?  Skip first row and combine the second fields unit the last line of the input file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:-

```
awk '!(NR%2){printf "%d\n", $2}NR%2{printf "%d\t", $2 }' file
286048  151
473     12030
197     107401
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have other rules that are not specified in the question based on the expected output in the comments.  This will print based on my interpretation of your requirements: skip first line, pair the following lines' second fields and only print pairs...

```
$ awk 'NR==1{next} {if(NR%2) print v, $2; else v=$2}' file

151 473
12030 197
```